# @Autowired Repository null

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

`ExampleRepository` injected by `@Autowired` annotation into test class works well, but injected into service class is null. Why does it happen and how can I fix it?

`Repository class`

```
public interface ExampleRepository extends JpaRepository<Example, Long> {

    // ...
}
```

`Service class`

```
@Service
public class Feed {

    @Autowired
    private ExampleRepository exampleRepository;

    private File file;

    public Feed(String file) {
        this.file = new File(file);
    }

    // ...
}
```

`Test class`

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
@SpringBootTest
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
@Rollback(false)
public abstract class ExampleTests {

    @Autowired
    private ExampleRepository exampleRepository;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        restoreInitialData();
    }

    protected void restoreInitialData() {
        this.exampleRepository.deleteAll();
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        Feed feed = new Feed("example.json");
        Optional<Example> example = feed.ingest();
        assertTrue(example.isPresent());
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Remove `final`.

Comment: @M.Deinum Problem still exists

Comment: Then you are creating new instances of the class yourself instead of letting Spring manage the instance creation. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896870/why-is-my-spring-autowired-field-null

Comment: Talking about variable not being injected in `Feed`, you need to also show us there do you get the `Feed` instance, and how do you use it. So, in short, provide a [mcve]

Comment: @M.Prokhorov Ok, I updated the code.

Comment: @TheChosenOne, see M.Deinum's comment. Autowiring will not work if you create things yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `@Repository` annotation to the interface `ExampleRepository`

Comment: No it doesn't as it is a Spring Data JPA repository.

Comment: Is JpaRepository not part of Spring Data JPA?

Comment: Yes it is but you don't need `@Repository` for them to be detected. Spring Data automatically detects repositories extending the Spring Data `Repository` interface (which is one of the super interfaces of `JpaRepository`.